# Discord уходит в низкий приоритет

Tags: windows-10, discord

Один из процессов Discord'а уходит в низкий приоритет, из-за чего наблюдаются проблемы с голосовой связью.
Обычно наблюдается в момент нагруженности проца.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обшарив несколько топиков с такой же проблемой, нашёл только батник, который каждые пять секунд присваивает, заранее, указанному процессу определённый приоритет.. Но и он не помогает.

```js
@echo off
set /p nazwa=Program Name:
echo Wybierz Priorytet:
echo 64     low
echo 16384  below normal
echo 32     normal
echo 32768  above normal
echo 128    high
echo 256    real time
set /p poziom=select:
wmic process where name="%nazwa%" CALL setpriority %poziom%
set "WMIC_CMD=wmic process where name^="%nazwa%" get /format:list ^| findstr Priority"
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%A in ('%WMIC_CMD%') do set PRIORITY=%%B
set startpriority=%priority%
:start
set "WMIC_CMD=wmic process where name^="%nazwa%" get /format:list ^| findstr Priority"
for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%A in ('%WMIC_CMD%') do set PRIORITY=%%B
if "%startpriority%" NEQ "%PRIORITY%" wmic process where name="%nazwa%" CALL setpriority %poziom%
timeout 5
goto start
pause
```

Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой или что можете посоветовать?

Comment: В Винде есть настройка Performance Options, вкладка Advanced. Пункт Adjust for best performance of и два выбора: Programs и Background services. Может не тот выбор стоит?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, никогда туда не лазил, так что стоит по дефолту "Оптимизировать работу: Программ"

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov эта опция отдает больше времени активному окну. приоритеты процессов она не меняет.

Comment: приоритет поменяй. а вообще это вроде из-за как раз таки нагрузки на проц. нужен посильнее, или убери что-то на фоне.

Comment: @user339218, я менял, он через пару секунд уходит обратно в низкий.
Причём интересное то, что только дискорд и только этот процесс изменяется.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cA5zU-n6O4E вот решение
сам с такой столкнулся помогло

Comment: @user346544 Пожалуйста, добавьте главное из видео прямо в Ваш ответ, иначе, скорее всего, его тут удалят. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение без танцев с бубном можете найти здесь:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZF-LURTScI

А именно, надо запускать дискород с флагом `--disable-renderer-backgrounding`.

Comment: На этом сайте необходимо добавлять решение проблемы прямо в Ваш ответ. Если ограничиться только ссылкой, то ответ, скорее всего, удалят. Спасибо.

Comment: Отмечу как правильный, вдруг кому поможет. В данный момент проблема уже не актуальная, ибо ребята с дискорда сами всё пофиксили.

Answer (score 1):

Держите скрипт, который каждые 5 секунд все процессы Discord'а повышает на высокий приоритет. https://github.com/AlexPigalyov/BatScript-DiscordFixLowPriority

Comment: Юзал подобный скрипт и ничего. Сейчас эта проблема не наблюдается, потому что сами разрабы это пофиксили.